# Counting consecutive selections of a given number when sampling integers in a range

Tags: python, random, statistics, simulation

This script counts consecutive number strikes of a number that you determine in a number-sequence that you also determine.

I would be very pleased if this script can be reviewed in terms of compactness, readability and quality. If this is perfect, please also let me know. But I am shure it will not be.

[The script can be tested here](https://repl.it/@Dexter1997/Count-Consecutive-Strikes?language=python3&folderId=)

```
import random

desired_number = int(input("Desired number: "))
lower_range = int(input("Lower range: "))
upper_range = int(input("Upper range: "))
iterations = int(input("Iterations: "))

consecutive_strikes = 0
biggest_strike = 0

for i in range(iterations):
  actual_number = random.randint(lower_range, upper_range)
  print("Actual number: ", actual_number)

  if actual_number == desired_number:
    consecutive_strikes += 1
  else:
    if (consecutive_strikes > biggest_strike):
      biggest_strike = consecutive_strikes
    consecutive_strikes = 0

# if all numbers are the desired number, the second if-statement in the for-loop  
# would never be executed 
if (consecutive_strikes > biggest_strike):
  biggest_strike = consecutive_strikes

print("Biggest consecutive strike: ", biggest_strike)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you never need to use the loop index, you should name it `_` instead of `i`.

```
for _ in range(iterations):
```

If statements don’t need parentheses around the entire condition.  You did it properly for the first `if`, but the last two you added extra parentheses.

You can use the `max` function to simplify the tracking of the `biggest_strike`:

```
biggest_strike = max(biggest_strike, consecutive_strikes)
```

replacing two lines of code with one.  And you get to do that twice.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) for this.

Just [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) the value to get groups of equal values, filter for the desired value, then get the length of each streak and finally take the `max` of that length:

```
from itertools import groupby

def longest_streak(values, desired_value):
    return max(len(list(group))
               for value, group in groupby(values)
               if value == desired_value)
```

(I think it should be [streak](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/streak), 4. b: "an uninterrupted series" and not [strike](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/strike?s=t).)

Then your main can code become this:

```
from random import randint

if __name__ == "__main__":
    desired_number = int(input("Desired number: "))
    lower_range = int(input("Lower range: "))
    upper_range = int(input("Upper range: "))
    iterations = int(input("Iterations: "))

    numbers = (randint(lower_range, upper_range) for _ in range(iterations))
    print("Biggest consecutive strike: ", longest_streak(numbers, desired_number))
```

Here `numbers` is a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), so the function can just consume the numbers as they are generated (meaning that this will occupy at most `len(group)` space in memory).

[`if __name__ == "__main__":` is a guard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) so that the code under it is only executed when directly executing this script, but not when importing from it.